# Request not found ajax spring mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I have a table with people. When I click on the delete icon, I want to delete that person from the database and on success delete the line from the table. 
I constantly get `deleteEmployee?id=37 not found 404`.
I have a controller with `@RequestMapping(value = "/deleteEmployee", method = RequestMethod.GET)`. 
The person I clicked was deleted from the database (checked) so the controller should be ok. But why do I get an error?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/deleteEmployee", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void deleteEmployee(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = true) int id) {
    System.out.println(id);
    employeeDAO.deleteEmployee(id);
}


$(document).on('click','.delete-emp', function(){
    deleteEmployee(this);
});
function deleteEmployee(el){
    var id = $(el).parent().attr('data');
    console.log("delete: "+id);
    $.ajax({
        url: "deleteEmployee?id="+id,
        success: function(){
            deleteRow(id);
        }
    });
}

function deleteRow(el){
    var row = $('.employee-row[data='+el+']');
    var shiftRow = row.next();
    console.log("deleting "+row+" "+shiftRow);
    row.remove();
    shiftRow.remove();
}
```

Comment: You should confirm you have mapped ajax url to controller method' `@RequestMapping`.

Comment: Don't return void, return a httpStatus OK. `@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)`

Comment: What is url of you current page and context path?

Comment: Use ModelandView class to return instead of void.

Comment: @TCHdvlp Can you please comment a shor example how would I implement httpStatus? Shoudl I put return value as httpStatus instead of void? Or I just put '@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)' before void?

Comment: @ParthTrivedi I want to just refresh the database, I don't want to return neither model neither page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use @ResponseBody  annotaion in your method is alone enough . this will solve your problem .

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/android/api/home", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody void Home(Locale locale, Model model,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    //your logic
}
```

add the content type in ajax call

```
jQuery
        .ajax({
            url : controllerUrl,
            data : oMyForm,
            dataType : 'text',
            processData : false,
            contentType : false,
            type : 'POST',
            success : function(data) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: I tried that with void and i got an empty page. I want to stay on the page without refreshing it. Just to fire the ajax which deletes a row in db than delete the same row in the DOM table. Row from db was deleted, but I got error response so the rows in DOM arent updated.

Comment: you could simply return a string in response body i am updating my answer see above you will stay in the same page

Comment: you cant return a string if you have declared your function `void`. But, this is the idea on how to solve this issue.

Comment: @TCHdvlp  yes sorry for the void .

Comment: add the content type gives you the answer

Comment: This fixed my issue. Thank you for your help!